# Is The Last Man on Earth on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is [The Last Man on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Man_on_Earth_(TV_series)) on-topic?

Comment: Post-apocalyptic shows (especially where there's a specific genesis for the apocalypse) should be on-topic. Can you explain why you think it wouldn't be?

Comment: Related: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5351/does-a-work-being-set-in-post-apocalyptic-future-automatically-make-it-in-scope

Comment: @Richard: Well, it's something of a sitcom.  I kind of feel like if I asked a question, it would get a lot of pushback.

Comment: @ThePopMachine So is [tag:red-dwarf]. I don't see why that would preclude it.

Answer (score 5):

By all accounts it sounds post-apocalyptic enough:

> The year is 2020, Phil Miller (Will Forte) is seemingly the only human left on Earth after a deadly virus swept the planet one year earlier.[5] An average man "who likes Star Wars, Twinkies, and sex",[6] Phil searches North America in his RV for other survivors. After a long journey, Phil returns to his hometown of Tucson, Arizona believing that he is Earth's last surviving human. Just before he attempts suicide out of loneliness and a desire for a female companion, his prayers are answered, and he meets Carol Pilbasian (Kristen Schaal), an irritating and obnoxious woman

Bear in mind, that you should focus on the speculative fiction aspects of the show.